# Facebook like button gets URL correct but not the meta information

Tags: facebook, metadata, facebook-like

I'm implementing a like button but for some reason the info in the meta tags is not being transferred properly.

If I place the URL into the `<fb:like></fb:like>` tags then the correct URL is loaded into the wall post on FB. But the image and all the other items described in the meta tags doesn't post with it. If I leave the `href` out of the `<fb:like></fb:like>` tags then the link defaults to the page the like button is on. Unfortunately, I need to add some parameters to the link so when the user clicks through to the site from the FB post, it shows correctly.

I've run my link through the link linter and it still shows the same image and the basic site information in the wall post, not the image or the description in the meta tags that shows up in the linter.

Basically, it looks like some of my meta information is being ignored. What am I doing wrong? Is this a cache issue?

*EDIT* I just tested this in IE and I get an error where the like button should be that says the page can not be found...

The head of the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Product Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/folder/folder/gateway.cfm?ifcn=1&amp;fbx=true&amp;type=product&amp;product=771&amp;page=gateway" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/folder/folder/images/theImage.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="ADMIN_ID123" />
```

Just inside the body tag:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

My Like button:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.mysite.com/folder/folder/product.cfm?pid=562&ifcn=1&fbx=true&type=product&product=562&page=gateway " show_faces="false" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: where is the 'fb-root' element in your html?

Comment: @emaillenin, I've updated the code to show where it is in my page. It's right after the opening `body` tag.

Comment: I think you need this doctype to use opengraph meta tags.
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
And also try modifying the xmlns:og as follows
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"

Comment: @emaillenin, No luck. I changed the doctype and the xmlns:og declaration and still no luck. I don't have an app-id in the `FB.init` function. I'm going to try adding one and see if that does anything for me.

Comment: Still no luck. Even with an appID. Something so simple, yet so frustrating.

Comment: did u enclose the appId in single quotes?

Comment: It'd be also helpful to try your product URL after deleting all Cookies for that site. Maybe you have a front-page which appears for users, who never visited that site before.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook like buttons don't like query strings, they need to be encode and even that doesn't work in some browsers.

Try running the link your trying to like through the [Facebook Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/). It can give you some useful information and even errors.